# HTML fieldset with two legends - top and bottom

Tags: css, html, legend, fieldset

I'm currently using a `fieldset` and `legend` to draw a box around some inputs i have in a form that looks something like this:

```
---------Caption---------
|                       |
|       inputs          |
|                       |
|                       |
-------------------------
```

I'm curious if there is a way to put another caption (`legend`) on the bottom of the box like so:

```
---------Caption1--------
|                       |
|       inputs          |
|                       |
|                       |
--------Caption2---------
```

Simply using another `legend` tag at the bottom of the fieldset does not work....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fieldset` and `legend` have a 1:1 relationship by definition. One `fieldset` must not have more than one `legend`element inside. You may use any other Element and use CSS to style it so it looks like a `legend` though.

Comment: so in order to achieve this I have to use css to position my text over the border along the bottom, and give it a background the same as the content background so you wont see the border striking through the text? It's do-able for sure but just seems like there should be an easier/more elegant solution for this...

Comment: Well, I don't consider this a very common case, so I'm not surprised it involves some CSS: Afer all it should't be much more than 10 or so lines...

Comment: I have trying to achieve the same, very useful answer but you would think that at some point there would be a way of setting multiple legends on a fieldset

Answer (score 3):

You can have only one `legend` element per `fieldset`, by HTML syntax, and if you try to use two `legend` elements, only the first one is displayed as a legend. The second one is treated as normal content.

Using CSS to style a bottom legend is not as simple as it may sound, partly because IE applies padding for `fieldset` differently from other browsers (and HTML5 CR). But the following seems to give fairly consistent results on CSS-enabled browsers:

```
<style>
fieldset { position: relative; padding: 0.35em 0.625em 0.75em; }
.legend2 { position: absolute; bottom: -1.4ex; left: 10px; background: white  }
caption, .legend2 { padding: 0 2px }
</style>

<fieldset><legend>Caption <span class=legend2>Caption2</span></legend>
  Put fields here.
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not on the top and bottom, it is on top right and top left. It seems not crossbrowser compatible.

I use this code for my webpage:

```
<style>
fieldset { margin:0; }
legend:after { position:absolute;content: attr(secondlegend);left:20px;background: #fff; }
</style>

<fieldset><legend secondlegend="Console" align="right"><button>clear</button></legend>
This is the content<br>of this fieldset
</fieldset>
```

But i use it as a console with the clear-button
So in the second legend-attribute i write the *real* Legend